# Running migrations while changing database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm making a multi tenancy application. For reasons I've chosen to go with a database for each of the tenants, and then a *"master"* database which contains meta information about the different tenants, and such.

I've therefore grouped my migrations into two directories:

- **Master** - which contains the migrations for the master database.
- **Tenants** - contains the migrations for each tenant database.

Instead of having to specify the path to the migration folders and the database to run on, each time I migrate, I've created a console command instead. However this is where the issue occurs.

I handle tenants using the subdomain as an identifier for which database to load from, using a middleware like this:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $domains = explode('.', parse_url($request->url())['host']);
    if (count($domains) < 3)
        return app()->abort(403, "A valid subdomain is required");
    \Config::set('database.connections.tenant.database', $domains[0]);
    return $next($request);
}
```

This works fine for web.

However when I use `Config::set()` within my console command, it's being ignored, and Laravel is just using the one from my .env file.

database config file:

```
return [
    'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'tenant'),

    'connections' => [
        'tenant' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database'  => env('DB_TENANT_DATABASE'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', '')
        ],
        'master' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database'  => env('DB_MASTER_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        ],
    ]
];
```

(I've cleaned it up a bit, so only the essential is shown).

In my .env file I've then specified a default tenant database, which is used when I'm using the cli.

```
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_MASTER_DATABASE=master
DB_TENANT_DATABASE=company
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Within my TenantMigrater I iterate through each tenant, and run migrate for each of them with a different connection and path.

```
foreach(Tenant::all() as $tenant)
{
    $this->info("Running migrations for the tenant: {$tenant->name}");
    \Config::set('database.connections.tenant.database', $tenant->database);
    $this->call('migrate', [
        '--database' => 'tenant',
        '--path' => 'database/migrations/tenants/'
    ]);
}
```

Although I'm setting a new database for the tenant connection, it's still falling back to the one specified in the .env file.

I tried going through Laravel's migrater, and as far I could see, the name was being set in the config correctly, so I'm feeling a bit confused. Any ideas?

Edit:
I think I've gotten one step closer to the issue. It seems like, when running php artisan *, the cli starts a connection to the database under the name specified in the config/database.php file. When i then try to override this, the connection is already open to the connection (or so laravel thinks), and it just hand my command the same connection, without setting the new database, hence why it keeps using the same database. However, I have no idea as to how to force it to create a new connection each time I iterate through the tenant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running \DB::reconnect('tenant'); before each migration seemed to make it work. This is a bit counter intuitive I think though.